# printf in C with strings that has shorter initializer behaves weird

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf, initializer

So I tried to make character arrays and play around with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    char str1[11] = "Yo! Angelo!~";  //total length of 12, initializer is shorter
    char str2[14] = "Yo! Angelo!233"; //total length of 14, initializer is same length
    char str3[60] = "Yo! Angelo!wwww"; //initializer is longer

    printf("%s"\n, str1);

}
```

the compiler gives me the warning that `initializer-string for array of chars is too long`

I expected that it will only give me the first 11 characters of str1, which is `Yo! Angelo!` without '~'

but this is I got all three arrays in a line (first one is first 11 chars) as this

`Yo! Angelo!Yo! Angelo!233Yo! Angelo!wwww` (all three strings smashed together without space)

the same problem still exist when I changed the initializer to length of 12 (same length as the string)

also, when I try  `printf("%s\n", str2)`, it has similar problem -- it prints second and third string in one line without anything in between

but when I change it to 13 or larger, it only prints str1, as intended.

It's not emergency and I know I must have the string declared longer than its length (longer than 13 in this case) but I just wonder why does printf do funky things like this.

Thank you～

Comment: You can't use `%s` to print character arrays. The `%s` format specifier is for strings only.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Errr... Sorry I'm a newbie in C, but `char str_name[size];` nearly what all the tutorials show to define a string... so could you please tell me what is a proper way then? (I always thought char array and string are the same thing)

Comment: Think about how `strlen` works.

Comment: If you use `char example[4] = "abcd";`, C allows the initialization (omitting the null byte — C11 [§6.7.19 Initialization ¶14](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14), but see also [¶2]((http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p2)); the result is a byte array, not a string.  [§7.1.1 Definitions of terms ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1): _A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character._ You are best off letting the compiler count; use `char str1[] = "Yo! Angelo!~";` — it doesn't make mistakes in counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a string initializer that is too long for the array, you lose the trailing characters, including the trailing NUL terminator.  So you end up with arrays (str1 and str2) that don't contain strings (no NUL terminator), so when you try to print it as a string, you get undefined behavior.  Specifically, it prints whatever happens to follow the array in memory, which turns out to be the other arrays.

Comment: The compiler is required to complain if you use an initializer that is too long (C11 [§6.7.9 Initialization ¶2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p2): _No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized._ That's a constraint; a diagnostic is mandatory. Some compilers might then go on to truncate the initializer, I suppose. It's not an area I ever bother to investigate as the code is clearly flawed. Since `char str1[11] = "Yo! Angelo!~";` tries to place 12 characters plus a null byte in 11 bytes of data space, it's bogus.